# Create a heat map using a subsection a distance object in r

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have a distance object

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=5)
d<-dist(x,diag=TRUE,upper=TRUE)

         1        2        3        4        5
1 0.000000 7.683422 8.210562 6.522327 6.091876
2 7.683422 0.000000 8.296771 6.641323 8.088297
3 8.210562 8.296771 0.000000 7.229307 6.133479
4 6.522327 6.641323 7.229307 0.000000 5.668197
5 6.091876 8.088297 6.133479 5.668197 0.000000
```

I want to create a heat map of only part of the distance matrix so I convert it to a matrix and subsection it i.e.

```
dm<-as.matrix(d)
dm[1:2,4:5]
         4        5
1 6.522327 6.091876
2 6.641323 8.088297
```

I now want to convert it back to a distance object so I can apply the following function to create a heat map. Any advice on how to either 1) convert the matrix back into a distance object so the function can handle it OR 2) adjust the function so that it create the heat.map without needing D to be a heat map. Thanks.

#

```
# coldiss()
# Color plots of a dissimilarity matrix, without and with ordering
#
# License: GPL-2 
# Author: Francois Gillet, August 2009
#

"coldiss" <- function(D, nc = 40, byrank = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
{
    require(gclus)

    if (max(D)>1) D <- D/max(D)

    if (byrank) {
        spe.color = dmat.color(1-D, cm.colors(nc))
    }
    else {
        spe.color = dmat.color(1-D, byrank=FALSE, cm.colors(nc))
    }

    spe.o = order.single(1-D)
    speo.color = spe.color[spe.o,spe.o]

    op = par(mfrow=c(1,2), pty="s")

    if (diag) {
        plotcolors(spe.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels, 
            main="Dissimilarity Matrix", 
            dlabels=attributes(D)$Labels)
        plotcolors(speo.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o], 
            main="Ordered Dissimilarity Matrix", 
            dlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o])
    }
    else {
        plotcolors(spe.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels, 
            main="Dissimilarity Matrix")
        plotcolors(speo.color, rlabels=attributes(D)$Labels[spe.o], 
            main="Ordered Dissimilarity Matrix")
    }

    par(op)
}

# Usage:
# coldiss(D = dissimilarity.matrix, nc = 4, byrank = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
# If D is not a dissimilarity matrix (max > 1), then D is divided by max(D)

# Example:
# coldiss(spe.dj, nc=9, byrank=F, diag=T)

# byrank= TRUE      equal-sized categories
# byrank= FALSE     equal-length intervals
```

Comment: From your comments to my answer it is not clear at all what you want to do. Please clarify.

Comment: I have re-worded the question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: It's certainly more complicated, and an altogether different question. I've deleted my answer, since it no longer answers your original question.

Comment: @Andrie Of course. Thank you for helping me clarify my question.

Comment: I really think you should have asked a new question. What you have done here is to waste my time trying to answer one question, then asked a completely different question. To be honest, that doesn't motivate me to help you in future.

Comment: @Andrie I am sorry you feel that way. But helping to clearly define the question is not a waste of time is it? The question is still my original question but with more detail due to you comments. Helping to define a  question in order to create a useful  resources for future r users must surely be important and is by no means a waste of time. Your answers are always well-structured and useful and it would be a shame to not have your input in the future so I hope you will re-consider. All the best, -Elizabeth

Comment: Think about what a distance object is. Now think about what a 2x2 matrix is. Now think about how you can turn any 2x2 matrix into a distance object. Now describe what you want to see in this 'heat map'. The answer may be as simple as image(dm[1:2,4:5])

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks this was useful. Any way you could change your comment into an answer and possibly add how to remove the numeric axis and add row and column labels (i.e. 1,2,4,5). Thanks again.

Comment: @Elizabeth I fear you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what SO's purpose is. It is _expected_ here that when you post a question, it is clear, complete and reflects your actual problem. Some clarification will occasionally be necessary, but this **isn't** a place to flesh out vague or incomplete questions. Editing questions such that they invalidate existing answers is generally considered, at best, rude, and should be avoided.

Comment: @joran I will keep that in mind for future posts